# Changing command names within the terminal

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, renaming

How do you change the names of commands within a terminal - I want to customise some of the commands just for a bit of fun, eg, instead of having to type python, I want to be able to type snek. I know it's silly but it's been a long day and I'd love something to cheer myself up - any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a Linux environment, you can make an alias to the Python executable (a more detailed guide here https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/set-command-aliases-linuxubuntudebian/)

If you're in a windows environment, you can just make a .bat file (walkthrough guide here https://fossbytes.com/what-is-a-batch-file-in-windows-how-to-create-a-batch-file/)

Hope you feel better after your day!  :)

Comment: Thanks so much, this really helped! Feeling much better :)

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Go to your `.bashrc` file in your home folder
2. Use an editor like vim or nano to edit the file
3. Go at the bottom and on a new line write `alias snek='python'`
4. Close the file and run `source .bashrc`. This will load the `.bashrc` file again.
5. Now you can just write `snek` and python prompt will open.